# How to Change Web Application Base URL via Nginx

Tags: nginx, url, nginx-reverse-proxy, base-url

I have the following basic Nginx location configured:

```
location /truenas/ {
  proxy_pass https://192.168.1.111:8443/;
}
```

However, the web app that I'm trying to proxy isn't aware that the URL path now starts with `/truenas/` and keeps looking for various files as if `/truenas/` was not in the path resulting in 404 errors.  For example, if I access the web app via `https://192.168.1.111/truenas` and look at the browser's developer tools network tab I see a GET request for `https://192.168.1.111/ui/assets/scripts/product.js`.  In order for this to work though the application should instead make a request to `https://192.168.1.111/truenas/ui/assets/scripts/product.js` (notice the `/truenas/` start to the path).  Is it possible to configure Nginx to somehow tell the application that the URL path now starts with `/truenas/` and it should modify its requests accordingly?